# transform all xml elements into txt with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to iterate over all nodes and subnodes (recursively) in xml and transform elements to txt format. E.g:

```
<root>
  <level>
    <data1>data1</data1>
    <sublevel>
       <data2>data2</data2>
    </sublevel>
  </level>
</root>
```

i want the following output in txt format:

```
root
  level
    data1:data1
    sublevel
      data2:data2
```

my current xslt transormation is:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>: <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

but it not produces desired output. there are some mistakes:

- the name of the element is transformed only for root node
- there are empty lines if there are empty elements (i want to suppress empty lines)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>

        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space(.)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(':', .)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

MSXSL output:

```
root
    level
        data1:data1
        sublevel
            data2:data2
```

Comment: thanks Kirill, your solutions looks good, but I need to format the output (it is another requirements). the output txt should corespond with the input xml (see my question: txt output representation). the output from your example is all pushed in one line. can you advise me how to format the output? thanks.

Comment: @zosim, Don't set `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />`

Comment: I have discovered why it was pushed.. because I'm looking the output in the firefox. There is it still pushed. But when I copy it and paste to the editor it is displayed correctly (formatting is OK). Another interesting finding is, that if I'm looking the output in IE 9, there are only data displayed (missing elements names, and also missing elements which are empty).

Comment: @zosim, Try to set `<xsl:output method="text" />`

Comment: It helped. Now is everyting OK. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
xsl:value-of select="local-name()"
```

with

```
xsl:value-of select="text()"
```

You can test for empty values with an `if`:

```
<if test="text() = '' >
```

I haven't tested the code, but should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Below may be a good push into the right direction: output needs indents and sub-elements not to be output - but I guess you will be able to figure it out :-).

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:call-template name="nodeToText"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="nodeToText">
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>: <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
        <xsl:call-template name="nodeToText"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Which leads to the following output:

```
root: data1data2
level: data1data2
data1: data1
sublevel: data2
data2: data2
```